# Почему в DearPyGUI не получается добавить виджет в основное окно?

Tags: python, gui, dearpygui

Я написал такой код:

```
from dearpygui.core import *
from dearpygui.simple import *

set_main_window_size(740, 520)

with window("window", width=720, height=480):
    set_window_pos("window", 0, 0)




start_dearpygui()
```

Он создает большое, нестилизованное окно (основное), и второе со стилями.

Когда я хочу добавить виджет в основное окно (вне with window()), мне дает ошибку

```
Exception: Error: [1000] Message:       Error parsing Dear PyGui 
command: Marvel::add_button

 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "UI.py", line 9, in <module>
         add_button()
SystemError: <built-in function add_button> returned a result with an error set
```

Это так задумано? Зачем вообще нужно основное окно? Можно ли его скрыть?

Comment: Почему вы выбрали именно эту библиотеку для знакомства с GUI?

Comment: Почему для знакомства? Я изучал wxWidgets, Tkinter и PyQT. Решил, что эта подходит мне больше всего, потому-что Tkinter слабый, PyQT трудно управлять кодом, wxWidget тоже что и Tkinter.

Comment: Читайте документацию тогда.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло. Удалить вопрос надо по здешним правилам?

Comment: @BadCoder если разобрались самостоятельно, вы можете добавить свой ответ, это может помочь другим участникам и будущим посетителям сайта.